# express does not set cookies in Production but they are visible in respoonse tab

Tags: express, cookies

II have an exppress app witch works correctly in dev.
However, when i do try to set cookies in prod, cookies are visible in network tab, but do not present in the browser.
I did a research and i think i covered most common problems, still cookies are not set
You may see my express app
I do add express configuration file, which i post here as well

```
         const app = require("express")();
            require("./config/express")(app);
            app.disable("x-powered-by");
            app.use((req, res, next) => {
              res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "example.com");
              res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
              res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
              res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
              res.setHeader(
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
              );
            
              if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
                // return res.sendStatus(200);
              }
              next();
            });
//express config.js
         const express = require("express");
            const path = require("path");
            const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
            const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
            const jwt = require("express-jwt");
            const jwks = require("jwks-rsa");
            const cookieSecret =
              process.env.COOKIESECRET ||
              "aabbcc";
            // const { errorHandler } = require('../utils')
            const expressSession = require("express-session");
            const config = require("../config/config");
            const helmet = require("helmet");
            const morgan = require("morgan");
            
              app.use(express.json());
              app.use(bodyParser.json());
              app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb" }));
            
              app.use(cookieParser()); // TRY to use it with secret as in the __express.js file
              app.use(express.static("uploads"));
              app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
              app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__basedir, "static")));
              app.use("/static/uploads", express.static("static/uploads"));
              app.use("/files", express.static("files"));
              app.use(helmet());
              app.use(morgan("combined"));
            
              // app.use(errorHandler(err, req, res, next));
                 app.use(
                    expressSession({
                      secret:
                        "aabbcc",
                      resave: false,
                      saveUninitialized: true, cookies,
                      cookie: { secure: true, sameSite: "none", domain: 'example.com' }, 
                    })
                  );
                  app.set("trust proxy", 1);
                };

     const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
     res.cookie(authCookieName, token, {
                                          expires: expiryDate,
                                          httpOnly: true,
                                          secure: true,
                                          domain: "example.com",
                                        });
    
                                        res.cookie(secondCookieName, secondToken, {
                                          expires: expiryDate,
                                          httpOnly: true,
                                          secure: true,
                                          domain: "example.com",
                                        });
    
                                        res.status(200).send(user).end();
                                        return;
```

Comment: The screenshot you posted (and removed) shows that you're using a URL (starting with `https://`) in the cookie's `domain`, which isn't correct. It should be a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it appeared, that this is the problem here

This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute is invalid with regards to the current host URL
This is seen as message in the response-headers.

But i do set all domains correcty. I tried with https as well as without it

Does any ever had the same problems?

PS : Both Front end and back end run on subdomains of a main domain

backend.maindomain.com - my backend
frontend.maindomain.com - my frontend

maindomain.com - landing page from witch you are rediirected to the app front end if you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It appears you need to set the main domain name as domain and cookies are being set on each subdomain

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using helmet. I too faced this problem, and it was solved by removing helmet. I know its not a solution, just a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion, but please keep in mind that removing the problem is not the same as solving it

Comment: I just shared my experience, maybe I'm wrong about helmet issue. And I've mentioned too that its not a solution

Comment: Nope, Helmet did not help in that case :(